# How do you make a POST request with text/plain post body?

Tags: ruby, curl

How do I make a POST request in Ruby (with any library) and pass a text/plain body?

Currently, I am using Curl and it doesn't seem to work:

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/post_endpoint'
c = Curl::Easy.new(url) 
c.timeout = 20
c.connect_timeout = 20
c.dns_cache_timeout = 20
c.ssl_verify_peer = false
postData = "dummy"
c.http_post(postData) do |c|
d = 1
end
```

(it just times out)

Comment: For sure you can. A body is a body, it's up to the server to interpret it. Maybe it's the one that can't parse the body or hangs for a long time.

Comment: Try with `curl` from command-line, for example. If that hangs, problem is 100% in the server (or the network)